# SHOW STATUS creates temp disk tables

Tags: mysql

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Created_tmp_disk_tables'.

Everytime I run that query through phpmyadmin another disk based temp table is created.

Is there a way to prevent it?

Edit : Looks like doing anything in phpmyadmin is creating temp disk tables.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is running a lot of queries itself just to display all the information about database objects. It might just as well be the side effect of the way it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is so... I have now tested on 3 servers (2 of them MySQL 5.1, one is 5.0), I have run the command several times and number of temp tables did not increase. Which MySQL version do you have? On which platform? Anyway, if it would be true, I would say it is a bug, because showing a variable should not need to create a temp table.

So it seems that some other queries which are running on your server are creating those disk temp tables and increasing your count.

Comment: I was running it through phpmyadmin. Looks like doing anything in phpmyadmin like switching from one database to another creates temp disk tables.

MySQL client version: 5.1.58

Comment: In that case phpmyadmin itself is doing something which needs temp tables. You can enable logging of all queries in MySQL server to see what exactly phpmyadmin is doing. But it is doing lot of things (like counting tables in each database, reading its config from db and many more).